# Wicket: Is it possible to update label value from the thread?

Tags: java, wicket

For example I have a html span which should be updated when the application is doing some tests (like do post, then wait some time for the response and represent result). So I want to show on this span current progress of this action.

I've tried create thread in myPage.java which extends WebPage. It's definition is:

```
class TestThread extends Thread{

    private Label current_message_lbl;
    private Component component;

    public void run() {
        try {
            this.sleep(1000);
            current_message_lbl.setDefaultModelObject(new StringResourceModel("test-SENDING-COMMANDS",component, null));
                    /* HTTP POST and other test code*/

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void setCurrentMesssageLabel(Label current_message_lbl){
        this.current_message_lbl = current_message_lbl;
    }
    public void setComponent(Component component){
        this.component = component;
    }
}
```

And I start it with:

```
TestThread thread = new TestThread();
thread.setCurrentMesssageLabel(current_message_lbl);
thread.setComponent(component);
thread.start();
```

And after I'm getting this error message

> There is no application attached to current thread Thread-103

I've tried also define thread like:

```
class TestThread extends WicketApplication implements Runnable{
```

Comment: If you are spawning a separate thread and return the HTTP response from the main request thread, how the updated piece of information is supposed to get to the user's browser?

Comment: Take a look at the [WicketStuff Push project](https://github.com/wicketstuff/core/wiki/Push), which provides the capability you seem to be going for (i.e. updates from server-side moving to client side).

Comment: Through the current_message_lbl.setDefaultModelObject. In wicket when I do it in the web page class, it updates information without browser, but if I add sleep() in the web page class, the page is stuck and it's not possible to do anything

Comment: Andriy, the reason for this is probably that without the sleep, the update of the model happens fast enough to get Wicket notice it while it gets to the render phase.

Technically, I don't think your approach is feasible unless you go for a server-side push (@see cometd, websocket and co).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add [AjaxSelftUpdatingTimeBehavior](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/ajax/AjaxSelfUpdatingTimerBehavior.html) to your component. Than this Behavior updates the component in every seconds or else. But you must change component's model in your Thread.

Also if you try to lazy load a component you can check [AjaxLazyLoadPanel](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/AjaxLazyLoadPanel.html). There are some examples in [here](http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples/ajax/lazy-loading) and [here](http://www.mkyong.com/wicket/how-do-use-ajaxlazyloadpanel-in-wicket/).